# Java JPA error; You have attempted to set a value of type class data expected type of int from query string

Tags: java, jpa

I have error of java JPA project below. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Type Exception Report

**Message** You have attempted to set a value of type class data.CityMake for parameter cityMakeMakeID with expected type of int from query string Select f from Foodmodel f WHERE f.cityMakeMakeID = :cityMakeMakeID order by f.foodModelName.

**Description** The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Exception**

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class data.CityMake for parameter cityMakeMakeID with expected type of int from query string Select f from Foodmodel f WHERE f.cityMakeMakeID = :cityMakeMakeID  order by f.foodModelName.

org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:933)

org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:593)

dao.FoodModelDAO.getModels(FoodModelDAO.java:69)

servlets.StartServlet.processRequest(StartServlet.java:67)

servlets.StartServlet.doGet(StartServlet.java:86)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

--------------------------------FoodModelDAO.java---------------------

public class FoodModelDAO 
{

```
  public static List<Foodmodel> getModels(int makeid)
  {

    CityMake make = CityMakeDAO.findMakeById(makeid);

    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
    String qString = "Select f from Foodmodel f " +
                     "WHERE f.cityMakeMakeID = :cityMakeMakeID  " +
                     "order by f.foodModelName";

    TypedQuery<Foodmodel> query = em.createQuery(qString, Foodmodel.class);

      query.setParameter("cityMakeMakeID", make );

    try
    {
        List<Foodmodel> models = query.getResultList();
        return models;
    }

    catch(NoResultException e) 
    {
        return new ArrayList<Foodmodel>();
    }
    finally 
    {
        em.close();
    }
  }
```

}

---------------FoodModel.java post 4/2/2018-----------------------
    I have updated FoodModel post again.

```
enter code here




@Entity
public class FoodModel {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long    foodModelId;
private String  foodModelName;


@OneToOne
private CityMake cityMakeMakeID;

public FoodModel() {

    foodModelName = "";

}

public FoodModel(Long m, String v, CityMake makeObj) {
    foodModelId = m;
    foodModelName = v;
    //citymake = makeObj;
    cityMakeMakeID = makeObj;
}

public Long getModelId() {
    return foodModelId;
}

public void setModelId(Long id) {
    foodModelId = id;
}

public String getModelName() {
    return  foodModelName;
}

public void setModelName(String value) {
    this.foodModelName = value;
}

public CityMake getMake() {
    //return citymake;
    return cityMakeMakeID;
}

public void setMake(CityMake make) {
    //this.citymake = make;
    this.cityMakeMakeID = make;

 }
```

}

Comment: public Foodmodel(Integer foodModelID) {
        this.foodModelID = foodModelID;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
    query.setParameter("cityMakeMakeID", makeid);
```

**Why?** You are creating a typed query for Foodmodel.class, so the parameter types should correspond with the model (looking at FoodModel, the attribute is defined as int).

```
    @Column(name = "CityMake_MakeID")
    private int cityMakeMakeID;
```

If your model was defined like this, the way you are doing it should work:

```
    @OneToOne //Or any type of relation that matches your needs
    private CityMake cityMakeMakeID; //See the variable Type
```